# What is the meaning of the word "dull" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

"Your critical thinking abilities have been **dulled**."

TFD def for the adjective "dull"
4. Intellectually weak or obtuse; stupid.

TFD def for the verb "dull"
To make or become dull.

These are the definitions that somewhat fit here but not entirely because they seem to describe a person. What I mean is that abilities cannot be made stupid, people can.
Is it the correct definition?

Comment: I've said it before, try another dictionary besides TFD. Oxford and Cambridge are better.

Comment: TFD usually includes just about everything that the average learner might need to know - it's just not always that well presented. In this case, the relevant meaning can be arrived at by combining the *verb* definition ***to make or become dull*** with the *adjective* definition ***lacking in perception** or the ability to respond; insensitive*.

Comment: I was thinking about that combination FumbleFingers but is it really so? Does it mean "Your critical thinking abilities were made so as to lack in perception"? Abilities don't lack in perception, people do. If the sentence was "Your critical thinking have been dulled." it would make perfect sense to me. I hope I was able to communicate what i don't uderstand.

Comment: The sentence essentially means that critical thinking abilities have *become weaker*, *grown weak*, etc. It's just idiom, so you can't lean too heavily on dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 1):

'Dull' is literally used about blades, e.g. of knives, where it is the opposite of 'sharp'. You can 'dull' a knife, or make it dull, by trying to cut stone with it. These words can be applied figuratively to people's abilities, (not just the people themselves). You often hear of rock stars' hearing having been dulled by prolonged exposure to loud sounds.

Comment: Also, dull versus shiny. :)

Comment: I'd always considered it 'the opposite of sharp', as in 'not the sharpest knife in the drawer'. We don't say 'not the shiniest spoon'. There's also 'dim' for 'not too bright'. [Not that it's truly important, just thinking out loud ;)